# which android version supports android.media.MediaFile?

Tags: android

Does android 1.5 or 1.6 support android.media.MediaFile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no class android.media.MediaFile in the sdk. [android.media](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary.html)

The class is definitely part of the [Android os](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/media/java/android/media/MediaFile.java&q=MediaFile&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc) but it must be internal so you should not use it.

Comment: However, nothing prevents you from copying that class in your code, with another package - and then use the modified class in your projects. Just make sure to publish any changes you may be making to the class, in compliance with the Apache license.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to the API. On top of nearly every class there's a version info, from which version it is supported ;-)